# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] while using ui-router state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angularJs and trying to write a simple program involving states. I am using the ui-router library.

On running my program in the browser is shows the following error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Here is my code:

```js
(function(){
 'use strict';

 angular.module('tryingApp',['ui.router'])
 .config(RoutesConfig);

 RoutesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

 function RoutesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/me');

  $stateProvider
  .state('me',{
   url:'/me',
   templateUrl:'firststate.html'
  })
  .state('nome',{
   url:'/nome',
   templateUrl:'secondstate.html'
  });
 }
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html ng-app="tryingApp">

 <head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

  

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  

 </head>

 <body>


  <ui-view></ui-view>


   <a ui-sref="me">click me!</a>
   <a ui-sref="nome">no, click me!!</a>



 </body>

</html>
```

In addition to the above to html and javascript files, I have the following two html files for firststate.html and secondstate.html respectively:

firstate.html:

```
<h3>Yay, this is me!! first state</h3>
```

secondstate.html:

```
<h3>Yippee!! this is me, second state!!!</h3>
```

These are all the files that I have.

Comment: have you added/installed `ui.router` dependency ?

Comment: I am using the ui.router library through the CDN link, isn't that sufficient? @UsmanRana

Comment: @whateverMan I see that this is correct. When I use that code in my local server there is no `[$injector:modulerr]` error. That error must be from somewhere else. Post your entire code.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I have updated the post with all the files. I just have 4 files in total, one index.html, one script.js and the other two are for the states.

Comment: @whateverMan I do not get any single error and the routing is working absolutely fine.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Interesting it is not working for me in chrome, but it is working in Safari and Firefox. Maybe some issue in Chrome, thanks anyway!!!

Comment: @whateverMan I am using chrome and works fine

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Interesting, It doesn't work for me, though my Chrome is up to date. hmmm....

Comment: @whateverMan I have the exact code from above and works fine

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal  Got it working!!! Had to clear the cache!! LOL.   Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was working in other browsers but was not working in Google Chrome. I had to clear the browsing data and Cache to get it working. Everything else is correct.

Leaving this for people who come across this problem in future.